# Will IDEA support application templates (ADT 20)?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Will the next version of IDEA support application templates feature which comes with ADT 20?

[image]

Details on this feature:

> Application templates: Android ADT supports a new application
>   templates for creating new application, blank activity, master-detail
>   flow, and custom view. These templates support the Android style guide
>   thus making it faster and easier to build beautiful apps. More
>   templates will be added over time.

Comment: I think proper place for this question is on JetBrains forum. But as far as I know here are present some JetBrains developers too.

Comment: Yes, they are and I hope some of them will answer. Many of us want to know the answer

Comment: File a request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA, it would be a good start.